# Converting 2D cell of 2D matrices (consistent sizes) into 4D matlab double

Tags: arrays, matlab, double, cell, reshape

Searching around here one finds many questions how one can convert cell arrays of doubles into one big matrix.
In my application I have a two dimensional cell array (lets call it `celldata` of size `m` times `n`) of all same sized double matrices (lets say of size `a` times `b`).
I want to convert that data structure into one bit 4D double (`m` times `n` times `a` times `b`).
At the moment I do that by

```
reshape(cat(3,celldata{:}),m,n,a,b)
```

but maybe there are other methods doing that directly? Maybe with a call like

```
cat([3 4],celldata{:,:})
```

or similar.

Comment: Have you given `cell2mat` a try yet?

Comment: Hi Dan, yes, I did - and Rody did also - like in his answer. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you dislike about your current solution?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Just the idea that there might exist a built-in function for doing that faster with one call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think

```
cell2mat(permute(celldata, [3 4 1 2]))
```

will do the trick. However,

```
%// create some bogus data
m = 1.1e2;
n = 1.2e2;

a = 1.3e2; 
b = 1.4e2;

celldata = cellfun(@(~) randi(10, a,b, 'uint8'), cell(m,n), 'UniformOutput', false);

%// new method
tic
cell2mat(permute(celldata, [3 4 1 2]));
toc

%// your current method
tic
reshape(cat(3,celldata{:}),m,n,a,b);
toc
```

Results:

```
Elapsed time is 1.745495 seconds.  % cell2mat/permute
Elapsed time is 0.305368 seconds.  % reshape/cat
```

`cell2mat` is a matlab m-file (with necessary inefficiencies in the loop due to compatibility issues), while `reshape` and `cat` are built-ins. This is where that difference comes from.

I'd stick with your current method :)

Now, I'm asking you why you'd want to do this convesion in the first place. Is it an indexing problem? Because

```
celldata{x,y}(w,z)
```

prevents you from having to do the conversion, so you can index like

```
converted_celldata(x,y,w,z)
```

I don't see other reasons, because matrix/vector operations don't work anyway on 4D arrays...

Comment: Hi Rody, thanks especially for activating my brain that there exists that nice `permute` function. Your solution is interesting but indeed slower - and not really prettier than mine (from my personal point of view).  
Lets look further for another solution.

Comment: @BastianEbeling: I don't think there is a better/more elegant method than the one you already have. Matlab has many operations for vectors and matrices, *some* things for 3D arrays, but 4D (and higher) requires methods that work for arbitrarily-dimensioned data, very much like the one you already have.

Comment: @BastianEbeling: See my latest edit, and the question at the end.

Comment: Okay Rody - coming to your question: Each matrix containts specific data belonging to elements being related to the columns and rows of the cell-array (which is generated from other cells which contain more data fields of different types make the cell usage neccessary). I want to have the 4D-representation for beeing able to do `sum(converted_celldata,3)` for example.

Comment: @BastianEbeling: you mean like `cellfun(@sum, celldata)`?